# get user address in messenger chatbot with python in dialogflow

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot, facebook-webhooks

I am working on facebook messenger chatbot development i am having these facebook webhook error showing in picture. i want to make it with dialog flow using python language. the idea is to get user current and destination location.